# Is setting Target Platform Version in MSVC for some library to 10.x makes program incompatible for running on Windows Vista/7/8?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, build, cmake

**Visual Studio** provides **Target Platform Version** setting for **C** and **C++** projects. I'm building my code with **Target Platform Version 8.1**. But when I generate **MSVC** solutions with **CMake** for some third party libraries the default setting is **Target Platform Version 10.x**. Will be still possible to run my application on older **Windows** versions like **Vista/7/8** when the application uses libraries compiled with **Target Platform Version 10.x** ?

Comment: If you set target to Windows 10 that will allow you to use functions not present on earlier versions. If you do, that will of course be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested the scenario in the question using `GetIntegratedDisplaySize` function available in the **Windows** **SDK** starting from **Windows 10**. I tested the scenario with both static and shared library using **Target Platform Version 10.x** and executable using **Target Platform Version 8.1.** The results are as follow:

1. In the case of static library:

   Trying to link the static library using the function `GetIntegratedDispaySize` requires linking also of `OneCoreUAP.lib` where the implementation of the function is. Since `OneCoreUAP.lib` is **Windows 10** function when the **Target Platform Version** of the executable is set to **8.1** this library cannot be linked in it and the compiler produces link time error. Since the executable cannot be create it also cannot be run on any **Windows** version.
2. In the case of shared library.

   Since shared library uses **Target Platform Version 10.x** it links successfully to `OneCoreUAP.lib` required by `GetIntegratedDispaySize` function. Shared library `dll` file and import `lib` file are created. Trying to link the executable with import `lib` works and the executable which runs fine on **Windows 10** is created. Trying to start the executable packed alongside shared library `dll` on older **Windows** version (**Windows** 7 is used for the experiment) produces the error for missing `api-ms-win-core-sysingo-l1-2-3.dll`. Thus the executable cannot be run on older **Windows** versions maybe except all required `dll` files are redistributed with it.

Answer (score 1):

If the libraries are optional DLL's (i.e. you can run without them, just with degraded functionality), then there is a solution: use delay-loading. Delay-loaded DLL's are only loaded when you call the first function in that DLL. Now, when you're on Windows 7/8, avoid calling any such function, and you won't have load failures.

Static libraries may cause problems, because they're linked into your executable. That means Windows 7 won't spot exactly what's going wrong, but you still get problems when you try to call a function which was introduced only in Windows 10. However, if the static library only uses Windows 7 functions, it will work.

Comment: If my executable is compiled with **Target Platform Version 8.1**, but the static library uses **10.x** and uses **Windows 10** function can the problem be revealed even on build time?

Comment: @bobeff: Not sure. Why don't you try and report back?

Comment: Is some simple Windows API function available only on Windows 10 comes to your mind to try it?

Comment: I tested it with `GetIntegratedDisplaySize` function. I will report the result as edit of your answer.

Comment: My edit disappears. Maybe it has not pass moderation?

Comment: @bobeff: Did you edit your question? I don't see any trace of an edit.

Comment: @bobeff: Ok, found it. Yes, that indeed failed moderation - it's really an expanded question and you edited into my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153432/discussion-between-bobeff-and-msalters).